# Angular lazy loading: route to a specific feature component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement angular 6 lazy loading and I would like to have links in my main homepage that points each one to a specific feature component.

My project's hyerarchy is as it follows:

```
app.module.ts
|__homepage.component.ts
|__options.component.ts
|__feature.module.ts
   |__buy.component.ts
   |__sell.component.ts
```

**From the `homepage.component`, user might be able to directly access `buy.component` and `sell.component`.**

How should the routes or the links in `homepage.component` be structured in order to achieve this?

As you can notice from my code below, my lazy loading routes only points to the module, but the `''` route - which is triggered by default - is not always the one that the user would like to visit *(if he/she clicked on "sell", he would like to view sell component and vice versa for "buy")* and I would like to avoid creating a sub-home page for each module…

Here's my code on the routes so far:

> **app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'options',
    component: OptionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'buy',
    loadChildren: "../app/posts/feature.module#FeatureModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'sell',
    loadChildren: "../app/posts/feature.module#FeatureModule"
  }
];
```

> **feature.routing.ts**

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/buy',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'buy',
    component: BuyComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sell',
    component: SellComponent
  }
```

*PS: I'll be available for any clarification if needed*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a separate `path` for feature module say as `'inventory'` in `app.routing module`. And feature module will load its child routes `(buy and sell)` appropriately. With this you need not specify all your child routes of `FeatureModule` inside `app.routing.module`

app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'options',
    component: OptionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'inventory',     // some other path to load feature module
    loadChildren: "../app/posts/feature.module#FeatureModule"  
  }
];
```

EDIT :

So your routes to feature module would look like

`routerLink="/inventory/buy"` or `routerLink="/inventory/sell"` or simply `routerLink="/inventory"` which will redirect to `/inventory/buy`

Comment: Thank you! So, if I put a link on my home page, it would be as `routerLink="/inventory/buy"` and `routerLink="/inventory/sell"` or just `routerLink="/buy"` and `routerLink="/sell"`? Or am I wrong in both cases?

Comment: It will be `routerLink="/inventory/buy"` or `routerLink="/inventory/sell"`  or simply `routerLink="/inventory"` which will redirect to  `/inventory/buy`

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add this to your answer as an edit? I think it would be a very useful tip also for other people :)

Comment: Yeah sure thing, I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you make sub feature modules your routes also change.

You should create a route for your feature module and sub route for your component.

Example:

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'options',
    component: OptionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'feature',
    loadChildren: "../app/posts/feature.module#FeatureModule"
  }
];
```

**feature.routing.ts**

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/buy',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'buy',
    component: BuyComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sell',
    component: SellComponent
  }
```

**Navigate to route:**

```
routerLink="/feature/buy"
```

or

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/feature/buy");
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame that I can't accept two answers because yours is also a worthy and very good one! And it also works as well